# How to increase decimals in the display grid?

Tags: pine-script

I developed an indicator in TradingView and it is working good. However when I change from one instrument to another instrument, the grid display disappears when the instrument has several decimal numerals.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © chiguiro
//@version=5

indicator("ZonaDeCompra", overlay = true, format=format.price, precision=1)

period = input(14, "periodo")

float patadaabajo = if close[1] > open[1]
    (open[1]-low[1])
else
    (close[1]-low[1])
    
float SMA1 = ta.sma(patadaabajo, period)

float zonacompra = open - SMA1


SMAVOL = ta.sma(volume, period)


bool compra = close > SMA1 and SMAVOL > volume

plot(compra ? zonacompra : na, color = color.fuchsia, linewidth = 2, style = plot.style_linebr)

var lbl = label.new(na, na, "", color = color.orange, style = label.style_label_upper_left)
labelText = "Buy: " + str.tostring(zonacompra[1], format.mintick)

label.set_xy(lbl, bar_index, zonacompra)
label.set_text(lbl, labelText)
```

I have attached the image with

[Grid Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dt6z.jpg)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdagQ.png)

Can you please explain to me how do I fix the problem?

Comment: Please do not share your code as a screenshot. Copy and paste your code here and use the formatting options.

Comment: @BarisYakut I am new to this website. I apologize. I fixed it